# FFmpeg Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, codec

I'm having trouble using FFmpeg to host an RTSP server for continuous video streaming. The command I'm using is:

> ffmpeg -report -v verbose -re -stream_loop -1 -i store-aisle-detection.mp4 -c copy -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8888/mystream

Log:

```
ffmpeg started on 2023-12-29 at 15:35:47
Report written to "ffmpeg-20231229-153547.log"
Log level: 48
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[h264 @ 0x560863a19240] Reinit context to 720x416, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'store-aisle-detection.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2018-07-18T23:51:37.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:05.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1125 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, left), 720x404 (720x416), 1089 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-18T23:51:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 30 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-18T23:51:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
[tcp @ 0x560863b71e80] Starting connection attempt to 127.0.0.1 port 8888
[tcp @ 0x560863b71e80] Successfully connected to 127.0.0.1 port 8888
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input
Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- 
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 0x560863a20300] Statistics: 135494 bytes read, 0 seeks
```

Can anyone help me identify and fix the problem with this command? I want to loop the video infinitely on the RTSP server. I've tried variations with different formats (e.g., mp4 and ts), but the issue persists.

Any insights into resolving this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try installing and configuring an RTSP server as [mediamtx](https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx). The default TCP port is `8554`. After executing the server, try the following command: `ffmpeg -report -v verbose -re -stream_loop -1 -i store-aisle-detection.mp4 -c copy -rtsp_transport tcp -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream`. I think you are getting the error because there is no RTSP listener.

Comment: @Rotem i already install meidamtx. But the same error occur the reason i use "ffmpeg -report -v verbose -re -stream_loop -1 -i store-aisle-detection.mp4 -c copy -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8888/mystream" over "ffmpeg -report -v verbose -re -stream_loop -1 -i store-aisle-detection.mp4 -c copy -rtsp_transport tcp -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream" because when i use port 8554 it keep show me "Connection attempt to 127.0.0.1 port 8554 failed: Connection refused"

Comment: In case there is an issue with the MP4 input file, you may try streaming a synthetic pattern: `ffmpeg -report -v verbose -re -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=720x404:rate=59.94 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -ar 24000 -rtsp_transport tcp -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream`. The "connection refused" error may be related to Linux issues or maybe FFmpeg version issue (I am using Windows 10, and it's working).